# Why is my computer is very slow and CPU hovers around 95%?

Tags: cpu-usage

A bunch of different programs are taking up CPU. However, those are programs that's not even active.

They're not supposed to take that much CPU.

It's as if the CPU got downgraded or something.

What can I do ?

[image]

Comment: Is your CPU overheating or throttling? Can you use a utility like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to see what speed your CPU is running at and report back?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system has a bottleneck, but it seems most likely that one of the processes is a blocking process. I see the Visual Studio is unresponsive. Have you tried closing Visual Studio and anything that you may have been running or debugging from Visual Studio?
If closing Visual Studio doesn't help, you might consider a restart to release all threads. Once you've restarted, open each application and keep an eye on usage.